# Rendering Mailers view in a controller view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, preview

I want to preview a mailer view (newsletter) before it is being sent

I have a `newsletter_mailer.rb` and a `newsletter` mailer method, which has a corresponding newsletter.html.erb view

I know Rails 4.1 has a mailer preview, but its only on development.

Is there a way to use use that view as a template without using partials? (since I need to inject it in an iframe since it is an email with doctype, body, etc)

Comment: Why don't you want to use partials?

Comment: not really sure.. How is the mailer preview uses the view without a partial?